# I'm facing with this error while creating the first project in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
>    Error: spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
>         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:232:19)
>         at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
>         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>     Emitted 'error' event at:
>         at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:238:12)
>         at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:407:16)
>         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace ?

Comment: couldn't get you sir?

Comment: you need to give more informations if you want help, or your post will be closed

Comment: i'm trying to install angularjs ,it has successfully installed and when im trying to run the first project it is showing error.

Comment: Add your code in your post or provide a JSFiddle or so or we'll not be able to help you, info you are giving right now are not enough